# Console isn't showing up when running print() using LOVE2d with atom-editor

Tags: console, atom-editor, love2d

Using atom-editor 1.13 with the love-ide package installed to run LOVE2d 10.2 games (windows 7)

Apparently if you create a `conf.lua` file in the same folder as your `main.lua` file you can add some configuations to `main.lua`. So, I've got these lines of code in my `conf.lua` to show console.

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.console = true
end
```

But when I go back to my `main.lua` and type `print("ballz")`, all I see is a blank LOVE2d game screen with no extra console window. Not really sure if this is because I'm using atom editor or not. Everything seems to be PATH'ed correctly.

On a side note, whenever I run atom using the love-ide package it always tries to install some "dependecy files" like the hyperclick-love package, and the auto-complete-love package. These fail to install because I don't have git installed.. honestly I really don't know what git is, but neither it, hyperclick, or auto-complete seemed like requirements to run my game, so in the spirit of not installing unnecessary things onto my computer I never installed these things... annoying as it is to see this notification always pop up when I start atom. Anyone know if this is contributing to the issue, or know a way to remove these notifications or auto-download-attempts? My LOVE2d code still seems to run without these packages.

Comment: where do you put `print("ballz")`? Also I would recommend ZeroBrane Studio to you. It's simple and doesn't ask much.

Comment: my code looks like this:

`require ("conf")     

print("ballz")`

its really two lines but for some reason this is showing up on one line (though it doesnt matter). no other code in the .lua file

i've heard about zerobrane, and i would use it, but i've come to really like the atom-editor and it's dark look is better for my eyes. also really like the shortcuts it has for modifying text.

Comment: @yougetagoldstar How are you launching the file? (Through Atom, with a batch file, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm launching it through the Atom editor, specifically through the love-ide package. With the love-ide package installed there is a play button below the File, Edit, View, etc menu that can run your .lua files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Have you set up the terminal emulator in your configuration?
2. (Windows only) Try using the `lovec.exe` executable instead of the normal `love.exe`. The first one attaches to the console that executed the game, the second one ignores it.
3. Lua has a buffered output, try adding `io.stdout:setvbuf('no')` to the top of `main.lua`

Comment: okay, so I actually found out that you have to drag the entire folder onto the love.exe or the lovec.exe and not just the main.lua file to get the game to run. I was just dragging the main.lua file. Seems like the console also opened with love.exe because I have that conf.lua file with 't.console = true' and 'require ("conf")' in my main.lua file.

Maybe i can force atom to use the lovec.exe somehow, so i don't have to keep dragging the entire folder.

Comment: boom.... actually number 1 solved this. looks like there was a "terminal emulator" check in the settings of the love-ide package. I keep forgetting that there's a settings section in atom packages. Thanks man, now i can quickly see the console through atom.